# how to Zoom an image taking container midpoint as base using kinetic js

Tags: kineticjs

1)created stage

```
var stage=new Kinetic.Stage(
{
    container:'container',
    height:500,
    width:500
}
);
```

2)created layer

```
var layer1=new Kinetic.Layer();
```

3)added image with x:150,y:150,width:200,height:200  //image1 is added image name

4)applying zoom

```
function()
{
image1.scale({x:2,y:2});
layer1.add(image1);
stage.add(layer1);
}
```

i)when i apply above function for zoom its scaling taking image top-left corner as base 
but i want the image to scale/(rotate) taking center of container as base
what can i do?

ii)how can i always place center of image matching center of container irrespective of image width?

Comment: Setting an `offset` may be what you're looking for. Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: yeah i got it setting the offset..thank you